# Invoking C# methods from C++ with usage of CoreCLR on Linux

Tags: c#, c++, .net, coreclr

I've found [that code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/coreclr/hosts/unixcorerun/corerun.cpp) which allows to execute C# assembly on hosted CLR in Linux. But I want to invoke only some methods from C# dll. I've tried [this](http://www.codingvision.net/tips-and-tricks/calling-a-c-method-from-c-c-native-process) and [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0), but I've no idea how to *properly* on Linux include or redefine:

```
ICLRMetaHost, ICLRRuntimeInfo, ICLRRuntimeHost, CLSID_CLRMetaHost,
IID_ICLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo, CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
IID_ICLRRuntimeHost
```

Do you have any idea or link to some code that invokes C# from C++ with CoreCLR on Linux?

**I'm only interested in CoreCLR on Linux ( not Mono! ).**

Comment: Hmya, that's the defining question for CoreCLR and the basic reason that Microsoft open-sourced it.  *Somebody* is going to have to flesh out coreclr/src/dlls/mscoree/unixinterface.cpp in a Unixy way, extending it beyond the very simple ExecuteAssembly() entrypoint.  That somebody could be you.

Comment: Take a look at the Kestrel project how the interop with libuv, https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/e421b3f01c2a1875c36204abda3f8f029a1b0fa0/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/Networking/Libuv.cs. Maybe it's possible to marshal a function pointer into a c# delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found that in order to get delegate to C# function you have to use this three functions provided by coreCLR:

```
// this one first, to initialize coreCLR
int (coreclrInitializeFunction)(
            const char* exePath,
            const char* appDomainFriendlyName,
            int propertyCount,
            const char** propertyKeys,
            const char** propertyValues,
            void** hostHandle,
            unsigned int* domainId);

// this one to get delegate to your C# function
int (coreclrCreateDelegateFunction)(
              void* hostHandle,
              unsigned int domainId,
              const char* entryPointAssemblyName,
              const char* entryPointTypeName,
              const char* entryPointMethodName,
              void** delegate);

// this one on the end, to close coreCLR
int (coreclrShutdownFunction)(
            void* hostHandle,
            unsigned int domainId);
```

Here's my example code calling C# function that calls C++ method on C++ object: https://github.com/Marqin/simpleCoreCLRHost